# Publishing ASP.NET application using third party hosting

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have developed an ASP.NET C# Web application with 2 web forms and I have purchased a domain from Fasthosts in order to host my site. I have changed the server to be Windows-based and used the correct ftp details to upload my app to the site. The only problem I am having is that when the site is published I am receiving this error.

[image]

I am hoping that this issue is fairly easy to resolve. Any help on what I can do to get around this issue would be much appreciated. Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not provided details of any set up using IIS, I would imagine that your issue is that you have simply deployed the file and gone to the URL expecting the site to be there. Normally you'd have some setup to do, unless they are handling that for you?

Answer (score 0):

Have you make sure that you have setup your default page? Do they support .net core? Maybe this post https://windowswebhostingreview.com/troubleshoot-403-error-when-publishing-asp-net-core/ can help you.